# Please help to convert short jquery code to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jQuery conflicts and would like to know if someone can help me convert this small snippet of code to just plain javascript. It would really be appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
$('.menuH').hover(function() {
    $('.menuC').stop().animate({
        width: '90px'
    }, 333)
}, function() {
    $('.menuC').stop().animate({
        width: '-0'
    }, 333)
});
```

Comment: What's the conflicts you get? If you're using multiple versions of jQuery, try removing one or using `$.noConflict()`

Comment: im actually trying to disable the jquery from the other component entirely since it is used for flash and i have replaced it with html5. So i prefer to completely remove jquery libraries

Comment: this can be done with css.

Comment: jQuery is a library in JavaScript and you can view the unminified source file. If a JavaScript alternate is not available, check what these functions will do and implement it in your code

Comment: like setting keyframes on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but, possibly something along these lines?

```
var menuh_el = document.getElementById('.menuH');

menuh_el.onmouseover = function() {
    var time = Date.now();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if ((Date.now() - time) < 333) {
            menuh_el.width = (((Date.now() - time) / 333) * 90) + "px";
        } else {
            menuh_el.width = "90px";
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 10);
};

menuh_el.onmouseout = function() {
    var time = Date.now();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if ((Date.now() - time) < 333) {
            menuh_el.width = (((time - Date.now()) / 333) * 90) + "px";
        } else {
            menuh_el.width = "0px";
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 10);
};
```

You should probably replace `setInterval` with `requestAnimationFrame` instead though. Also, it differs in the jQuery code in the sense that it will not call `.stop()`, I'm not sure how to do this, I'm sorry :(